# "grep -v" search for entries in one file not in the other

Tags: bash, grep

Trying to use grep -v but not quite successful.
I read from the option page that:

> -v: Invert match.

```
file1="/path_to/ID.txt"
file2="/path_to/Large_anno.txt"
file3="/path_to/output.txt"
grep -v $file1 $file2 > $file3
```

file1 looks like this:

```
1_762443_G_T_b37
1_762491_G_A_b37
1_762494_C_G_b37
1_762523_T_A_b37
1_762525_A_T_b37
1_762526_G_A_b37
1_762527_G_A_b37
1_762531_C_T_b37
1_762536_G_A_b37
1_762536_G_C_b37
```

file 2 has the first column that's in the above format and another 90 columns with other information. Some columns have missing values. I have attached the first 16 columns.

```
1_762491_G_A_b37    1   762491  762491  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 0.0001  4.369   0   1   11400   
1_762526_G_A_b37    1   762526  762526  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 11.75   0   2   3       0.998
1_762527_G_A_b37    1   762527  762527  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 8.755   0   2   2   0   0.093
1_762541_G_A_b37    1   762541  762541  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 4.48    0   1   2   0.61    0.988
1_762565_G_A_b37    1   762565  762565  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 3.964   0   1   3   0.47    
1_762566_C_G_b37    1   762566  762566  C   G   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 4.111   0   0   4   0.192   
1_762631_G_A_b37    1   762631  762631  G   A   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 6.862   0   1   5   0.025   940
1_762637_G_T_b37    1   762637  762637  G   T   ncRNA_exonic    LINC00115   ncRNA_exonic    ENSG00000225880 0.0053  0.00139776          rs201219564
```

My goal is to identify things in file1 that are not in file 2 and output to file3.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Comment: @jww Hi, I did have my code in the first grey box when I asked the question. Do you mean that I should share all the code that I have tried? But some may not be so relevant and that will distract people from answering my specific question. I did not share the file format for file2 because it way too long..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible grep invocation would be:

```
grep -vFf <(cut -f1 -d' ' "$file2") "$file1" 

-v Invert match
-F Patterns are just strings, not regular expressions
-f Take the patterns from the specified file, one pattern per line
<(cut -f1 -d' ' "$file2") make an input file by using the `cut` utility
   to extract the first column of file2, where the column is
   terminated with a space character.
```

It would be optimal to anchor the match at the beginning of the line, but `grep` doesn't have a command-line option for that. Using `-w` to force the match to match word boundaries might cut down on false hits.

You could also use the Gnu `join` utility, but that requires sorting both files:

```
join -v1 <(sort -k1b,1 "$file1") <(sort -k1b,1 "$file2")
```

You can easily select which lines you want output: `-v1` selects lines only in file1; `-v2` selects lines only in file2; leaving out the `-v` option selects lines present in both files.

It is important that `join` and `sort` sort the files in the same order. This should normally be the case, but the way your locale treats whitespace in collation order can produce odd results. I added the recommended field selection options to the sort commands. Even safer (and slightly faster) would be to do both the sort and the join in the "C" domain rather than whatever is the default on your machine:

```
(LC_ALL=C; join -v1 <(sort -k1b,1 "$file1") <(sort -k1b,1 "$file2");)
```

Another option might be to use awk. The following prints the lines in file1 which were not seen in the first field of file2:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$1]++;next}!seen[$1]' "$file2" "$file1"
```

To switch that around, the easiest solution is just to reverse the order of the files in the invocation.

The first condition (total lines read equals lines read in this file) restricts the command to the first file (in the command line); the command marks the line in a hash-table and then skips the rest of the commands. The second condition therefore is only tried on the second (and subsequent) file arguments, and succeeds if the first field of the line is not in the `seen` hash; since it doesn't have an explicit action, the default action is used, which prints the line.

Comment: Hi @rici, the three methods are great, I have tested all of them. When I redirect the results from join to > $file3, there's an error message "join: file 2 is not in sorted order" but no error message when I don't redirect the results to $file3. Awk take a bit longer than the first two methods but it does print out all the rest of the columns. I really like all the methods and learned quite some, thank you.

Comment: @Molly_K: I don't know why join would behave differently based on whether the output is redirected or not. With join, you can easily choose to print the ids which are only in file1 (with -v1) or the ones which are only in file2 (with -v2). I wrote the awk solution thinking that you only wanted the ids which are only in file2; however, your question says that you want the ones which are only in file1 in which case there would not be any other columns.

Comment: Hi @rici, I tested the grep method, which gave me 120645 rows as unmatched results, With join, I got 65532 rows, with the awk method, there are 2072228 rows. I will update my question with file2 format as well. I am getting very confused.... thanks.

Comment: @Molly_K: How many rows are there in each file? (`wc -l /path/to/file` will tell you) Also, are there any duplicated ids?

Comment: @Molly_K: Ok, there were a couple of issues. The cut command (in the command substitution for the grep command) was assuming that fields were delimited by tab characters. I changed it to space characters by adding `-d1`. In the awk command, it was written to generate lines from file2 not in file1. I switched the order of the arguments so you can just copy and paste. With those two changes, all three provided the same answer on the sample data (7 lines printed). The field delimiter only matters in the grep case, and it makes the command a bit fragile. I'd use one of the other two.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The original file2 has 4691028 rows. I got consistent results from "join" & "awk" methods (120656 rows), which is only 3 rows different from the results of "grep" (without -d ' )' (120645 rows) ; once added -d ' ', the results is 2739464 rows. When testing cut -f1 $file2 or cut -f1 -d' ' $file2, I got the same row number as original file2, which is 4691028 rows. Do you think that the rest of the columns could affect the results of the output? I am happy with awk results, just curious about the why different methods would produce a slight different number.

Comment: Actually, when I look closer, although both "cut" resulted in the same row number as file2, cut -f1 -d' ' $file2 didn't cut out just the first column, all the columns were output together. cut -f1 $file2, on the other hand, properly cut out just the first column. So my file is tab delimited, right?

Comment: @molly_k sounds like it

Answer (score 2):

`-v` inverts the search string given as a string argument. To specify search strings not as an argument but as the lines of a file, you have to use `-f`:

```
grep -vf "$fileWithSearchStrings" "$fileToBeSearched" > "$outputFile"
```

> My goal is to identify things in file1 that are not in file 2 and output to file3.

Then you should try

```
grep -vf "$file2" "$file1" > "$file3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that is more flexible in some situations.  If you combine the lines from multiple files, you can find the unique lines easily.  So in your example:

```
cat "${file1}" "${file2}" "${file2}" | sort | uniq -u > "${file3}"
```

This is how it works:

1. **cat** combines file1 with two copies of file2
2. **sort** will sort the lines of the combined files
3. **uniq -u** will give you the unique lines, which cannot be from file2 since it is duplicated, and cannot be lines that are found in both file1 and file2

You can use this same method for many more files, catching the unique lines.  And if you want to see just the lines in common, that would be:

```
cat "${file1}" "${file2}" | sort | uniq -d
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @Charlie, thanks for the idea, I will use this when looking for overlapping data. For this post, I am looking for things that exist in file1 but not in file2. :)

Comment: Hi @Molly_K.  The example will actually give you the lines that exist in file1 but not in file2, since everything in file2 is duplicated, and the things in file1 only will not be.  Just try it out.